# Angular package creation and accepting dependancy injection from the consumed application

Tags: angular

I am trying to develop an angular4 package. And this package is supposed to be used by different angular applications. The package contains directives, services and models/contracts. This package should be working as a framework to invoke application specific code. My question is: How can I execute application specific code from the package? I just want to code against contracts in packages so that it can be reused across multiple applications. Just think about how angular execute our code if we develop angular application!  Parameters accepts through ForRoot() ??

Waiting for your valuable thoughts

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to pass code to a component or service in that module and want it to be executed there?

Comment: I want to execute the application specific code from package.

Comment: Like executing a method on the application that consumes the module?

Comment: Just assume package does have a rule engine. And the specific application does have rules defined. Application A's rules might be different from application B's. Package will trigger the rules after certain code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the method (code) you want to call.

```
ruleEngineService.methodToCallWhenSomethingHappens = this.executeRulesOrDoSomethingYouWant
```

In `RuleEngineService`,

```
whenSomethingHappens() {
    this.methodToCallWhenSomethingHappens()
}
```

Comment: Rule engine(package) needs to decide which (application code)rules needs to be executed. In other words package may not have any idea about it's concrete implementation. I am thinking just like code against abstraction.

Comment: Then pass the callback (the method in the application you want to execute) to the rule engine. This way, the package doesn't have to know about the consumer. It'll just execute whatever you pass.

Comment: Package needs to decide which one should execute.. I have solved it with ForRoot(). I accepts a parameter through ForRoot()  which should implement the contract which I specified with in my package.  Thank you very much for your answers.